# Page size of read (and write) operations

Tags: bitcoin-core, performance

I'd like to fine-tune the `recordsize` parameter of my ZFS file system used to store the blockchain and related data to optimize my public node's performance. Which page size does bitcoind (Bitcoin Core v25.1.0) use to read/write data? How does this differ for `chainstate` and `blocks`?